# getting "mysqli num_rows Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" error in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm having a problem with the a mysqli query I'm calling from a php script. I've rewritten it many times and keep getting the error:  "mysqli num_rows Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" This is the first attempt to access the database from this page. I was previously binding the parameters and then calling: $checkAcct->num_rows() and getting the same problem. I also tried what someone suggested in a different post on this site: 
    do { $checkAcct->use_result(); } while( $checkAcct->next_result() ); 
but this didn't work either and I got the same error. After I make sure a user with these details isn't in the db I execute another query to insert the user's info into the site but the error message I get pertains to this query here. Let me know if it would help to see the other query also.

Below is the code I'm trying to use:

```
$checkAcct = $dbConn->stmt_init();
$existingAcct = array();

if ($checkAcct->prepare("select usrName, eAddy from usr where usrName = ? OR eAddy = ?"))
{
    $checkAcct->bind_param("ss", $usr, $eml);
    $checkAcct->execute();
    $checkAcct->bind_result($result);
    while($checkAcct->fetch())
    {
        $existingAcct[] = $result;
    }
    if ($existingAcct[0] != 0)
    {

        if ($usr == $inputs['usrName'] && $eml == $inputs['eAddy'])
        {
            $acctSetupErrors[] = "Someone with your username and email address already exists. Please use the forgot password form to reset your password";     
        } else if ($eml == $inputs['eAddy'])    {
            $acctSetupErrors[] = "Someone with your email address already exists. Please use the forgot password form to reset your password or setup an account with a different email address";       
        } else {
            $acctSetupErrors[] = "Someone with your username already exists. Please choose a different username";
        }
    } 

    $checkAcct->free_result();
    $checkAcct->close();
```

**Edit**

Alright. I tried your way and it didn't work either so I went hunting for any previous db calls. I found the offending query in a db call in an include file linked higher up in the script. Funny, it's never caused problems anywhere else but now I freed the result and it works well. Thanks for your help with this. I don't have enough points to upvote you for suggesting it must be somewhere above in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change the above code like this and see what you are getting

```
$checkAcct = $dbConn->stmt_init();
$existingAcct = array();

if ($checkAcct->prepare("select usrName, eAddy from usr where usrName = ? OR eAddy = ?"))
{
    $checkAcct->bind_param("ss", $usr, $eml);
    $checkAcct->execute();
    $checkAcct->store_result();
    printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", $stmt->num_rows);
    $checkAcct->free_result();
    $checkAcct->close();
}
```

And could you make sure prepare buffer is cleared before you use it again. I hope there is some other query which is executed prior to this statement is still active in mysqli prepare statement buffer.

Comment: Thanks. It was a db call hiding in an include file that I didn't think to check.